# Monitoring number of consumer for the Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, grafana, apache-kafka-streams, prometheus

We are using Prometheus and Grafana for monitoring our Kafka cluster.

In our application, we use Kafka streams and there is a chance that Kafka stream getting stopped due to exception. We are logging the event `setUnCaughtExceptionHandler` but, we also need some kind of alerting when the stream stops.

What we currently have is, jmx_exporter running as a agent and exposes Kafka metrics through an endpoint and prometheus fetches the metrics from the endpoint.

We don't see any kind of metrics which gives the count of active consumers per topic. Are we missing something? Any suggestions on how to get the number of active consumers and send alerts when the consumer stops.

Comment: Are your consumers running as OS services?

Comment: No. its java application with kafka streams

Comment: You can run Java applications as systemd services which can be easily monitored and even restarted upon failure.

Comment: my service has not only the streams but also it handles other stuff. In case of exceptions, only the stream stops, and other keeps on running

Comment: Maybe adding a custom metric could help? https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html#adding-your-own-metrics

Comment: Thank you Matthias for the input. is there any out of solution it, rather writing some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we had similar needs and added Kafka Consumer Lag per partition into Grafana, and also added alerts if lag is more than specified threshold (threshold should be different per each topic, depending on load, e.g. for some topics it could be 10, and for highly loaded - 100000). so if you have more that e.g. 1000 unprocessed messages, you will get alert.

you could add state listener for each kafka stream and in case stream is in error state, log error or send email:

```
kafkaStream.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
    log.info("Kafka stream state changed [{}] >>>>> [{}]", oldState, newState);
    if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.ERROR || newState == KafkaStreams.State.PENDING_SHUTDOWN) {
        log.error("Kafka Stream is in [{}] state. Application should be restarted", newState);
    }
});
```

also you could add health check indicator (e.g. via REST endpoint or via `spring-boot` `HealthIndicator`) that provides info whether stream is running or not:

`KafkaStreams.State streamState = kafkaStream.state();
state.isRunning();`

I also haven't found any kafka streams metrics which provide info about active consumers or available connected partitions, but as for me it would be nice if kafka streams provide such data (and hope it will be available in future releases).

Comment: Thanks Vasiliy for your answer. I think the health check indicator will be the best option for me. But still, wondering, why this is not given as out of box solution.

Comment: I guess it's not given as out of box due to kafka streams provide current state info and state listener, and it's up to us to decide what we want to do with that, either add health check indicator (it could be done easily with spring-boot), or send emails in case stream is not running. I agree that it could be implemented in `spring-kafka` out of the box in future :)

Comment: Thanks again Vasiliy. Hoping for the same in `spring-kafka`.

Comment: If you use spring cloud kafka streams, then it shows the health stays of all listeners KStream, KTable and GlobalKTable on health status page. For some kafka streams gets down, it shows status as Down.