# How do you correctly write a Kafka Streams healthcheck?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka will internally kill any nodes that are not correctly polling, but we don't want bad nodes to stay up and we want visibility of which nodes are working, so naturally we want to build out a classical healthcheck.

The obvious way to build a healthcheck is to use `KafkaStream#state#isRunning` but this is completely deceptive. If the underlying network connection to Kafka is down, or any of a dozen things that don't cause an internal thread to die, `KafkaStreams` still reports itself as alive even though the logs are throwing up errors all over the place. Is there any correct way to get visibility of what is happening inside Kafka streams? Is expecting a sane healthcheck the wrong approach to take when dealing with Kafka?

To be clear, I am not talking about healthchecks of the Kafka *cluster*, specifically the Streams processor node.

Comment: Kafka Streams JMX metrics may be what you are looking for: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html

Comment: Unless I am missing something, none of those JMX metrics reveal whether the client is successfully heartbeating against Kafka. We may have low volume topics where a mean messages per second of zero is totally normal.

Comment: Understood. Possibly the `heartbeat-response-time-max` may help? https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#consumer-group-metrics.

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445293/monitoring-number-of-consumer-for-the-kafka-topic/51454631#51454631, it does not respond directly to your question, but has similar thoughts. you could have a health check indicator `KafkaStream#state#isRunning` as you mentioned. From another side, if network issue happens, you will have errors in your log. So you could setup alert on errors in log. Also you need to monitor Kafka lag. These three techniques should cover healthcheck.

Comment: That's a tricky question. `Kafka will internally kill any nodes` -> I assume you mean that those nodes drop out of the consumer group (because nothing get's actually killed by Kafka)? -- For JMX metrics, there is thread-level `process-rate` that should help to see if an application processes data or not.

Comment: Checking the lag might not help, as if a instance becomes a zombie and drops out of the group, a healthy instance would get those partitions assigned and there should be no lag as long as the remaining instances are healthy -- it recommended in general though to monitor lag to see if the overall application is health -- however, even if there is lag, it might be tricky to identify the zombie instance (that is not part of the group any longer) that does not process any data.

Comment: I a StreamsThread dies, you can learn about it via `KafkaStreams#setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` -- if all threads are dead, Kafka Streams would report state `NOT_RUNNING` (cf: ) -- there is also a proposal to introduce DISCONNECTED state: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-457%3A+Add+DISCONNECTED+status+to+Kafka+Streams

Comment: You could also have a `KStream#peek()` or a a wall-clock-time punctuation to implement a heartbeat to an external system.

Comment: if you can't manage JMX metrics to work and kafka metrics is enough, i suggest next approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/74233687/2872157