# Spring Actuator + Kafka Streams - Add kafka stream status to health check endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a spring boot app where I use apache kafka-streams. I don't use spring cloud streams. I added actuator health check endpoint. I configured it in the `application.yml` like that:

```
management:
  health.db.enabled: false
  endpoints.web:
    base-path:
    path-mapping.health: /
```

When a runtime exception was thrown and my stream was stopped as logs show but the health check status is UP.

`2019-09-17 13:16:31.522 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-5] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams : stream-client [lpp-model-stream-7e6e8fea-fcad-4033-92a4-5ede50de6e17] Streams client stopped complet`ely

How to bind kafka stream status to health check endpoint  ?

My pom.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>data-wizards</groupId>
                <artifactId>lpp-common-avro</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
                <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Link to the code where I create the stream: https://gist.github.com/solveretur/fc4fdd6c7663dc4d58fe72d48029f9c3

Comment: Have you tried by implementing a custom HealthIndicator?, you can override use the KafkaStreams.setExceptionHandler to mark an error in your custom HealthIndicator implementation.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do - implement a HealthIndicator - however I'am not proficient enough in Java / Spring / Kafka to do it and I would like to find some working example just to copy it into my project

Comment: I have answered this question based on my understanding below. If that is not working, can you provide a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example one can work on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

KafkaStreams maintain *an in-memory* `State` which could be mapped to Actuator's health statuses. State could be one of following:`CREATED`, `ERROR`, `NOT_RUNNING`, `PENDING_SHUTDOWN`, `REBALANCING`, `RUNNING` - they are self-explanatory. See docs for state transitions https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.State.html

If you're looking for a complete example, you could take following one and update it according to your needs (e.g. you may not count `CREATED` as status UP). Make sure you have a bean of type `KafkaStreams` in application context.

```
//Note that class name prefix before `HealthIndicator` will be camel-cased
//and used as a health component name, `kafkaStreams` here
@Component
public class KafkaStreamsHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    //if you have multiple instances, inject as Map<String, KafkaStreams>
    //Spring will map KafkaStreams instances by bean names present in context
    //so you can provide status details for each stream by name
    @Autowired
    private KafkaStreams kafkaStreams; 

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        State kafkaStreamsState = kafkaStreams.state();

        // CREATED, RUNNING or REBALANCING
        if (kafkaStreamsState == State.CREATED || kafkaStreamsState.isRunning()) {
            //set details if you need one
            return Health.up().build();
        }

        // ERROR, NOT_RUNNING, PENDING_SHUTDOWN, 
        return Health.down().withDetail("state", kafkaStreamsState.name()).build();
    }
}
```

Then the health  endpoint will display it like:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "kafkaStreams": {
        "status": "DOWN",
        "details": {  //not included if "UP"
            "state": "NOT_RUNNING"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically `KStream` is used to define the *topology* only, it doesn't contain any runtime information. Actual processing starts only when you create an instance of `KafkaStreams` and call its `start()` method. So you need it anyway, see this article for a good example https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-streams. Make sure you define a **bean** of `KafkaStreams` in Spring context. Should I update answer with example of `KafkaStreams` bean that is used for HealthCheck?

Comment: no I understand now  - the KafkaStreams is just hidden somewhere in the spring context in some spring dependency I have - i will accept your answer

Comment: I just figured you use kafka streams via spring-kafka. In that case, `KafkaStreams` beans are not exposed to context, it is managed internally by `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`. Hopefully you can obtain instance of `KafkaStreams` by `streamsBuilder.getKafkaStreams()`; so I suggest to define `KafkaStreamsHealthIndicator` in **java configuration** where you already have streamsBuilder.

Comment: I'm trying to adopt this solution but when i want to curl kafka health metrics. 
 `curl -v http://localhost:8080/actuator/health 

*   Trying ::1...


* TCP_NODELAY set


* Connection failed


* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused


*   Trying 127.0.0.1...


* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed


* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused` 
Any help ?

Comment: There are might be dozens of reasons and KafkaStreams indicator is unlikely to be a cause as you’re querying the root of app health status. Try searching for similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517713/unable-to-access-spring-boot-actuator-actuator-endpoint

Comment: idk what the resason, but in my case kafkaStreamsState is always Running even if I stop kafka and logs full of kafka DisconnectException

Comment: In my case, it works with :  
`@Autowired private StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factoryBean;`  
...  
`State kafkaStreamsState = factoryBean.getKafkaStreams().state();`  
My KStream is started by the Spring StreamsBuilder instance.

Comment: these solutions above do not work with Spring 2.7.14

Answer (score 1):

The health information is collected from all the beans implementing the HealthIndicator interface configured in your application context.

You can create a custom HealthIndicator which you can use to report the Kafka Streams error.

Create your HealthIndicator singleton bean as below

```
@Component
public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    private Exception caughtException = null;
    // Any other information you want to store.
    @Override
    public Health health() {

        if (caughtException == null) {
            return Health
                .up()
                .withDetail("status", "Kafka Streams Running")
                .build();
        }
        else {
            return Health
                .down()
                .withDetail("status", "Not Available")
                .withDetail("error", caughtException.getMessage())
                .build();
        }
    }
    public void setException(Exception caughtException) {
        this.caughtException = caughtException;
    }
}
```

Then you can Autowire this bean where you are using your Kafka Streams, and you can set the exception as follows.

```
public class MyApp {
    @Autowire
    private MyHealthIndicator healthIndicator; // You can also use constructor injection instead. 

    // Rest of the code


    public void init() {
        // Streams initialization code here
        streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread thread, Throwable throwable) -> {
            healthIndicator.setException(new Exception(throwable));
        });
    }

}
```

I hope this helps, but if it doesn't, please give a [Minimal, Verifiable, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Example which someone can work on

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Yurii J not working in my case.
kafkaStreamsState is always Running even if I stop kafka and logs full of kafka DisconnectException.
I came to next simple solution (for Kakfa health, not including Stores, etc):

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaStreamsHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Autowired
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        Search connectionsSearch = meterRegistry.find("kafka.producer.connection.count");
        Double kafkaConnections = Optional.ofNullable(connectionsSearch.functionCounter())
                .map(FunctionCounter::count)
                .orElse(0d);
        if (kafkaConnections > 0) {
            return Health.up().build();
        }
        return Health.down().build();
    }
}
```

Works like a charm, but you have to register kafka metrics using micrometer (MeterRegistry).
Here how we enabling kafka metrics:
in application.yaml - spring.kafka.streams.auto-startup: false
In java:

```
@Autowired
private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
...  
kafkaStreams.start();
Thread.sleep(KAFKA_STREAMS_START_DELAY); // 23000, yes this is strange, but we had an unexpected behavior - if enable kafka metrics without this awaiting, then metrics not registered actually
new KafkaStreamsMetrics(kafkaStreams).bindTo(meterRegistry);
```