# Client Healthcheck: Check for consumer/producer if broker is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have requirement to implement healthcheck and as part of that I have to find if producer will be able to publish message and consumer will be able to consumer message, for this I have to check that connection to cluster is working which can be checked using "connection_count" metric but that doesn't give true picture especially for consumer which will be tied to certain brokers on which partition for this consumer is.

Situation with producer is even more tricky as Producer might be publishing the message to any broker which holds the partition for topic on which producer is publishing.

In nutshell, how do I find the health of relevant brokers on producer/consumer sude.

Comment: maybe something like this would be helpful  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74233687/2872157

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, I divide the question into a few checks.

1. Can you reach the broker? `AdminClient.describeCluster` works for this
2. Can you descibe the Topic(s) you are using? `AdminClient.describeTopic` can do that
3. Is the ISR list for those topics higher than `min.in.sync.replicas`? Extrapolate data from (2)

---

On the producer side, if you set at least `acks=1`, and there is no ack callback, or you could expose JMX data around the buffer size and  if the producer's buffer isn't periodically flushed, then it is not healthy.

For the consumer, look at the conditions under which a rebalance will happen (such as long processing times between polls), then you can quickly identify what it means to be "unhealthy" for them. Attaching partition assignment + rebalance listeners can help here.

---

Some of these concepts I've written between

- [dropwizard-kafka](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/kafka/health/KafkaAdminHealthCheck.java) (also has Producer and Consumer checks)
- [remora](https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora/pull/62)

I would like to think Spring has something similar