# Kafka Health check in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, health-check

I need to add *Kafka* health checks in my spring boot app. I found some solutions ([Spring Boot: Kafka health indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64869177/spring-boot-kafka-health-indicator)) where *Kafka* was checked through **KafkaAdmin** (via `describeCluster()`). Also I'd like to check ability of application to consume and produce messages. Is it correct to check health/state of *Kafka* components with health topic? Is it correct to check *Kafka* components at all?